# Remove character from image url

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to PHP and WordPress, and i need to import image from a offshore website with the WordPress function download_URL().

My problem is, i have URL that look like that :

> http://www.test/img/FMR.jpg

But i have also URL that look like that :

> http://www.test/img/FMR.jpg?Qq_0y12h

And can i have remove everything that is after the .extension if there something?

Comment: You don't need a regex for this.

Comment: It is better to be taken care by rewrite rules rather than in code

Comment: You can use explode on the question mark and use the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use preg_replace, I did this little example for you.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.test/img/FMR.jpg?Qq_0y12h";

echo "url = $url\n\n";

$urlFormatted = preg_replace("/\?.*$/", "", $url);
echo "urlFormatted = $urlFormatted\n";

?>
```